# Get context for search string in text in C#

Tags: string, search

Given a string text which contains newline there is a search keyword which matches an item within the text.

How do I implement the following in C#:

searchIdx = search index (starting with 0, then 1, etc. for each successive call to GetSearchContext.  Initially start with 0.

contextsTxt = string data to search in

searchTxt = keyword to search for in contextsTxt

numLines = number of lines to return surrounding the searchTxt found (ie. 1 = the line the searchTxt is found on, 2 = the line the searchTxt is found on, 3 = the line above the searchTxt is found on, the line the searchTxt is found on, and the line below the searchTxt is found on)

returns the "context" based on the parameters

string GetSearchContext(int searchIdx, string contentsTxt, string searchTxt, int numLines);

If there's a better function interface to accomplish this feel free to suggest that as well.

I tried the following but doesn't seem to work properly all the time:

```
    private string GetSearchContext(string contentValue, string search, int numLines)
    {
        int searchIdx = contentValue.IndexOf(search);

        int startIdx = 0;
        int lastIdx = 0;
        while (startIdx != -1 && (startIdx = contentValue.IndexOf('\n', startIdx+1)) < searchIdx)
        {
            lastIdx = startIdx;
        }

        startIdx = lastIdx;

        if (startIdx < 0)
            startIdx = 0;

        int endIdx = searchIdx;
        int lineCnt = 0;

        while (endIdx != -1 && lineCnt++ < numLines)
        {
            endIdx = contentValue.IndexOf('\n', endIdx + 1);
        }

        if (endIdx == -1 || endIdx > contentValue.Length - 1)
            endIdx = contentValue.Length - 1;

        string lines = contentValue.Substring(startIdx, endIdx - startIdx + 1);
        if (lines[0] == '\n')
            lines = lines.Substring(1);

        if (lines[lines.Length - 1] == '\n')
        {
            lines = lines.Substring(0, lines.Length - 1);
        }

        if (lines[lines.Length - 1] == '\r')
        {
            lines = lines.Substring(0, lines.Length - 1);
        }

        return lines;
    }
```

Comment: Is this a homework problem or something? If it is, and you are honest then you might get some actual help with this. Otherwise I would just advise you to simply call the System.String method Contains(String) in order to do what you want.

Comment: I what you are looking for is slightly more complicated, but you can split a string on a newline into an array of lines, and then iterate over each line looking for your search string...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not actually a homework question.  i'm trying to build a personal search engine.  I just now figured out the problem as to why it didn't always work which was due to case-sensitive searching.

Just needed to add StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase and voila it worked!  I feel dumb for not thinking of that before posting.